# Windows 2008 Server: Found a trojan in c:\Windows\Fonts\winlogon.exe. How do I delete that?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virus-removal

Miscrosoft Security Essentials does not detect it, but from its CPU consumption and location in the Fonts folder it clearly is a virus. From Task Manager I right click on "winlogon.exe" to Open File Location but nothing happens, and right click to Properties shows its location as c:\Windows\Fonts.

If I copy the entire Fonts folder to "Fonts1", I see the winlogon.exe file there. But I cannot find a way to see it and thus delete it from the actual c:\Windows\Fonts folder itself.  This is running in Amazon EC2 so I don't think I can reboot in safe mode. How do I delete this file?

Comment: How did you find the file? Your anti virus should be able to locate this and quarantine it so you can delete it.

Comment: You can also boot from an antimalware rescue disk, e.g. Kaspersky's, created on another (non-infected) machine, and let the rescue disk clean up the virus. Use the rescue media immediately after downloading and creating it, because it will have the current malware file definitions on it.

Comment: I found the file by using Task Manager and right clicking on the task and its Properties.  It was consuming a lot of CPU so that's what lead me to it. Miscrosoft Security Essentials did not detect it. Other commonly used anti-virus apps like McAffee do not run on this OS. As stated this is in the Amazon cloud, so I cannot boot from a rescue disk. Thanks.